# Adobe Air 4.0 Native Extension with Google Play Services

Tags: android, admob, air-native-extension

These days, I am trying to integrate AdMob into my Adobe Air based android app, with **Google Play Service**. After I get the ane file ready, I got following error after I debug app in Flash builder 4.6:

> Error occurred while packaging the application:
>
> dx tool failed: UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/R$attr;   at
>   com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
>     at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:143)    at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:301)     at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:278)     at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$100(Main.java:56)    at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:229)
>     at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
>     at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:130)
>     at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:108)
>     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:247)  at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:183)  at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:139)  at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:120)     at
>   com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:89) 1 error; aborting

This problem is quite similar with post:
[Cannot build Android Release Build on Flash Builder 4.7 due to "dx tool failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455535/cannot-build-android-release-build-on-flash-builder-4-7-due-to-dx-tool-failed)

I know there must be something wrong with my ane file. But I really don't know where is the problem. Here is my android native extension .jar folder:
[image]

Here is my platform.xml file:

```
<platform xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/4.0"> 
    <packagedDependencies>
        <packagedDependency>android-support-v4.jar</packagedDependency>
        <packagedDependency>google-play-services.jar</packagedDependency> 
    </packagedDependencies> 
    <packagedResources>
        <packagedResource> 
            <packageName>com.google.android.gms</packageName> 
            <folderName>google-play-services-res</folderName> 
        </packagedResource> 
    </packagedResources>
</platform>
```

I am using following command line to compile the ane file:

```
adt -package -target ane Output.ane extension.xml -swc AdmobLibrary.swc -platform Android-ARM -platformoptions platform.xml -C android . -platform default -C default .
```

I can get the ane file. But after debuging my Flex app, the error is coming out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the problem solution. The problem is in the process of exporting native extension to .jar file. More specifically, when I export my android project to .jar file, I made a mistake. I select the whole java project files to export into .jar file, including gen folder which is not necessary. Here is the screen shot:

**What I am doing is incorrect:**
[image]

**This is the correct way:**
[image]